# Positioning issue Mapbox 3D model THREE.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, coordinates, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a custom layer for Mapbox to render 3D objects using Three.js. My goal is to load 3D objects onto the map and render them at specific latitude and longitude coordinates. While I've successfully loaded one object onto the map, I'm struggling to place objects at different lat,lon locations. The challenge is projecting the lat,lon coordinates to the threejs world.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { MercatorCoordinate, type Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

export type ModelOptions = {
  location: [number, number];
  rotation: [number, number, number];
  scale: number;
};

export default class Map3DLayer {
  private map: Map;
  private camera: THREE.Camera;
  private scene: THREE.Scene;
  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  private cameraTransform: THREE.Matrix4;
  private scale: number;

  constructor(map: Map) {
    this.map = map;

    // Build the scene
    this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: map.getCanvas(),
      context: map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl') ?? undefined,
      antialias: true,
    });
    this.renderer.autoClear = false;

    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 5);
    this.scene.add(light);

    // Synchronize THREE with Mapbox
    // const center = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(map.getCenter(), 0);
    const center = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat([0, 0], 0);
    const { x, y, z = 0 } = center;
    this.scale = center.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();

    const scale = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(this.scale, this.scale, -this.scale);
    const rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-0.5 * Math.PI),
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI),
    );

    this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .multiplyMatrices(scale, rotation)
      .setPosition(x, y, z);
  }

  loadModel(name: string, path: string, options: ModelOptions) {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      loader.load(path, ({ scene }: any) => {
        scene.name = name;
        this.scene.add(scene);
        this.update(name, options);
        resolve();
      }, undefined, reject);
    });
  }

  update(name: string, options: Partial<ModelOptions>) {
    const item = this.scene.getObjectByName(name);
    if (!item) return;
    const { location, rotation, scale } = options;
    if (rotation) item.rotation.set(...rotation);
    if (scale) item.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
    if (location) {
      const { x, y, z = 0 } = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(location, 0);
      item.position.set(x, y, z);
    }
    this.renderer.state.reset();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.map.triggerRepaint();
  }

  render(ctx: WebGLRenderingContext, matrix: number[]) {
    this.camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .fromArray(matrix)
      .multiply(this.cameraTransform);
    this.renderer.resetState();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}
```

I've tried using the MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat function from Mapbox to convert the lat,lon to x,y,z coordinates for Three.js, but the objects aren't appearing at the expected locations. I know this translates coordinates to a 0-1 range, and try to use the calculated scale to move objects to its correct location without luck.

Expected Behavior:
The 3D objects should be rendered at the specified lat,lon coordinates.

Actual Behavior:
The objects are rendered but not at the desired lat,lon coordinates.

Note that updating any any object's prameter should relocate it or rotate it in the threejs would, without affecting the camera.

Any insights or suggestions on how to project the lat,lon coordinates correctly to the threejs world would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified piece of working code:

```
import { CustomLayerInterface, Map, MercatorCoordinate } from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

export class ExternalModelDefinition {
    public url: string;
    public origin: [number, number];
    public rotation: Array<any>;
    public altitude: number;
    public scaleFactor: number;
}

function add3DModelToMap(externalModelDefinition: ExternalModelDefinition, map: Map) {
    const modelAsMercatorCoordinate: MercatorCoordinate = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(externalModelDefinition.origin, externalModelDefinition.altitude);
    const modelScale = modelAsMercatorCoordinate.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits() * externalModelDefinition.scaleFactor;

    // transformation parameters to position, rotate and scale the 3D model onto the map
    const modelTransform = {
        translateX: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.x,
        translateY: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.y,
        translateZ: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.z,
        rotateX: externalModelDefinition.rotation[0],
        rotateY: externalModelDefinition.rotation[1],
        rotateZ: externalModelDefinition.rotation[2],
        /* Since the 3D model is in real world meters, a scale transform needs to be
         * applied since the CustomLayerInterface expects units in MercatorCoordinates.
         */
        scale: modelScale,
    };

    //const THREE = window['THREE'];

    const camera = new THREE.Camera();
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight2);

    const customLayer: CustomLayerInterface = {
        id: 'your-custom-3D-object-layer-id',
        type: 'custom',
        renderingMode: '3d',
        onAdd: (map, gl) => {
            // use the three.js GLTF loader to add the 3D model to the three.js scene
            const loader = new GLTFLoader();
            loader.load(
                externalModelDefinition.url,
                (gltf) => {
                    scene.add(gltf.scene);
                },
                (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) => {},
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );

            // use the Mapbox GL JS map canvas for three.js
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                canvas: map.getCanvas(),
                context: gl,
                antialias: true,
            });

            renderer.autoClear = false;
        },
        render: (gl, matrix) => {
            const rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), modelTransform.rotateX);
            const rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), modelTransform.rotateY);
            const rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), modelTransform.rotateZ);

            const m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
            const l = new THREE.Matrix4()
                .makeTranslation(modelTransform.translateX, modelTransform.translateY, modelTransform.translateZ as number)
                .scale(new THREE.Vector3(modelTransform.scale, -modelTransform.scale, modelTransform.scale))
                .multiply(rotationX)
                .multiply(rotationY)
                .multiply(rotationZ);

            renderer.autoClear = false;
            camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);

            renderer.resetState();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            this.map.triggerRepaint();
        },
    };

    map.addLayer(customLayer);
    map.setLayoutProperty(customLayer.id, 'visibility', 'visible');
}
```

This must give enough guidance to make it happen  Good luck!

Comment: This is the same example in https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/. I'm actually able to position one element, but I can't add more than one and update them (look at my update function) while the camera is binded to a single object.

Comment: If you iterate `add3DModelToMap` from a list of externalModelDefinitions, placement of 1..n models will just be fine. For every model added to the map there is a new `Camera`, `Scene` and `WebGLRenderer` used. You are using the same instance which causes the malfunctioning.

Comment: Uh, I see. My intention was to load only a single map layer. What about performance overhead on adding everything multiple times?

Comment: It's not so much "adding everything multiple times", it is "adding everything in its own space a single time"  You can do some performance test yourself (10, 100, 1000, 10000) 3D models added to the map. And dive in to documentation of three.js scene, camera and WebGLRenderer to see if they should be resuable or if its common practice to place every 3D model in its own "space".

Comment: @markusand any progress? Please consider marking the answer... as THE answer 

Comment: Would also to love hear more about the results you have @markusand